# how to make a cylinder with several segments, from a csv file

Tags: python, texturing, scripting, csv

I'm new to Blender, even more so in the scripts.
I'm trying to make a cylinder (x,y,z variables) that contains several segments, these are controlled by a .csv file, where I get the depth.  These segments must have color, which will be given by another csv file.  Once the texture is done I want to rotate the cylinder.

```
inicio, fin, code
0, 25 , A
25, 50, B
50, 100, A
100, 115, B
115, 150, A
```

For it I have made a circle which I have been extruding, according to the data of the csv file, this in a for cycle, until here everything well, the problem I have is when I want to assign the color (texture) to each segment and the other problem is to achieve the rotation (the angle of rotation is delivered as a variable) since this must be from the point of origin of the first circle.

the code

```
import bpy
import csv

Lit = [] #anida los datos del archivo .csv

#leyendo data.csv
archivo = ('archivo.csv')
with open (archivo, 'r') as csvfile:
    archivo = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for row in archivo:
        Lit.append(row)

#coordenadas del circulo
_X = 100
_Y = 50
_Z = 120

#colors 
A = ('0.198,0.8,0.085,1')
B = ('0.8, 0.009, 0.010, 1')


INCLINATION = 45

INC = ((90-INCLINATION)*0.436332)/25

DIAMETRO = 2

for fila in range(1, len(Lit)):
    inicio = float(Lit[fila][0])
    prof = float(Lit[fila][0])-float(Lit[fila][1])
    print(prof)
    
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(radius= DIAMETRO, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(_X, _Y, (_Z-inicio)), scale=(1, 1, 1))
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(MESH_OT_extrude_region={"use_normal_flip":False, "use_dissolve_ortho_edges":False, "mirror":False}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, (prof)), "orient_type":'GLOBAL', "orient_matrix":((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), "orient_matrix_type":'GLOBAL', "constraint_axis":(False, False, True), "mirror":False, "use_proportional_edit":False, "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "use_proportional_connected":False, "use_proportional_projected":False, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "cursor_transform":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False, "use_automerge_and_split":False})
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

[image]

Comment: you must create each material and assign that to each segment. please show some code and some of your csv in order to help you+

Comment: I have just edited the information, attaching csv data and the code.  Thank you

Comment: Could you please clarify the rotation part.

Comment: Once the textures for each segment, is to rotate the object completely, for this I must join the segments and then move the pivot point to the coordinate _x, _y, _z, and then rotate, being the angle of rotation with respect to the X axis, the variable inclination, measured with respect to the horizontal, so the variale INC